# Where to implement BackgroundWorker. Winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, background, backgroundworker

I have created a UserControl using a DevExpress XtraTreeList. Basically in this user control I am using inventory Items. which are more than 30,000. Now when I load the complete table in my typed DataSet it takes almost 6-8 seconds.

The purpose to build the usercontrol is reuseability. So that we can use it in other parts of the application.

Now I am using this UserControl in a Winform, where this usercontrol is place in the left hand side on the form where it will be used as a Menu. The user is suppose to click its desired item by expanding the nodes and when the nodes is selected and then its further details will be fetched and will be displayed in the from. So far so good.

Now the reals issue is that in the same form along with other controls, we have a Devexpress XtraButtonEdit(build using a textbox and a button on the right handside). This buttonEdit is displaying the currently selected Item(from the treeMenu UserControl) code in its textbox, when we are clicking the buttonEdit button then we are loading another form as a model and displaying the same UserControl (XTRATreeList from DevEpress). The only issue is that when I am laoding this new form as a model. The tree again takes time to load which looks bit awkward.

To rectifiy this issue, I am trying to implement the Background worker thread, but bit confused that where should I implement that backgroundWork. In the User Control or in the form.

If I implement that Background worder in the UserControl then how can I access this BackgroundWorker thread and execute it on the main Form where I am using the UserControl on the left hand side as a Menu. Actually what I want is when user clicks the ButtonEdit control and the form loads, it should load like a flash or max in 2 sec....please help.... and execute it.

I hope that ppl will understand my issue.

If somebody finds any difficulty plz let me know....

Regards,

Comment: Meh, doesn't matter much.  It will take her an hour to find the needle in the haystack.  Solving her problem solves yours too.

Comment: Hans, mate I could't understand your comment, can you please explaing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to "access this BackgroundWorker thread and execute it on the main Form".

A user control could contain its own Bgw. You nee a synchronous method (on the UC) to start it. Then handle the completed (and mayb progress) events inside your UC.

But the data won't load any faster, you only unfreeze your main GUI.

Comment: Critical parts above: *handle the completed (and mayb progress) events inside your UC*. Even if you use a BW, make sure only UI work is done on the UI thread. If the it's the UI itself which is taking forever to load then use a control that understands paging or split up the UI access in batches.

Answer (score 1):

If the delay is caused in the code that loads the tree, then you should "thread" that part. I would recommend reading this sample chapter from C# in a Nutshell: http://www.albahari.com/threading/. They cover C# 4.0, but you should be able to apply most of the concepts to C# 3.0 if that's what you are using.